Derive the filter mask that corresponds to the double filtering process
There are two mask filters,
f1 = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
               [1, 1, 1],
               [1, 1, 1]]) / 9


f2 = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
               [1, -8, 1],
               [1, 1, 1]])

I filter an input image using f2 and then filter the result with f1, how can I derive the filter mask that corresponds to the double filtering process?
I want to get a combine filter mask.

This is not a question about programming. It is better asked over at [dsp.se].

This question was answered here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/93726/33605 — please delete this one.
